# My site blocked by facebook

Tags: facebook

I have a site and wanted to share it into facebook. However, upon posting I got a notification from facebook saying:

> The content you're trying to share includes a link that our security
>   systems detected to be unsafe:
>
> markleobongcasan.com
>
> Please remove this link to continue. If you think you're seeing this
>   by mistake, please let us know.

I checked into sucuri site check and it is 100% safe.

I checked my site using facebook debugger as what one of their support member suggested and I got this:
http://screencast.com/t/4nTfGhNd0fq2

Anybody here who has the same experience/problem? How did you fix it?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking or what you're trying to find out. Could you give some more details as to the nature of your problem? Are you using a proxy that doesn't allow the site?

Comment: "Anybody here who has the same experience/problem? How did you fix it?"

Answer (score 0):

"let us know" is a link. You need to click that link and appeal to Facebook. After that, all you can do is wait.

You can also try asking in the official Facebook Developers group: https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/

...or you could file a bug, because it could be a bug too: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: Actually I already filled that form out for over a number of times since last year but facebook support is shameful. No reply. Not even once. I can't believe a company as big as facebook fails on supporting issues.

Comment: well, the best thing you can do then is to switch to another domain, unfortunately. facebook gets a LOT of messages per day, afaik they handle support for blocked domains pretty lightly.

Comment: i´ve added some more information to my answer, which may help you